What is the "new altar" in musaf for Rosh Hodesh?
To what does this term refer: "mizbeach hadash b-Zion"?  It appears in the musaf amida for Rosh Hodesh.

There is currently no altar on the Temple Mount. We would like there to be one.

I think this is self-explanatory, it refers to a new mizbeach, aka the third Beis HaMikdash.

Why is this question downvoted?

The meaning becomes reasonably clear if the full sentence in which the words you quote (mizbeach hadash b-Zion) appears is set out:
מִזְבֵּֽחַ חָדָשׁ בְּצִיּוֹן תָּכִין
וְעוֹלַת רֹאשׁ חֹֽדֶשׁ
נַעֲלֶה עָלָיו
Establish a new altar in Zion,
and we will offer on it the Rosh Chodesh burnt-offering
The request is for the restoration of the Bet HaMikdash and the re-establishment of the altar for korbanot including the Rosh Chodesh olah (burnt offering)

So you are saying that the RH musaf amida was written post korban 2nd Temple?

@YehudaW Yes, it is certainly my understanding that the Amidah text was finalised after the Churban Bayit Sheni

If you like an answer, please consider accepting it. Otherwise, please comment on how it can be improved.
